# SQL XML query for update

Tags: sql

I have a tag like below.

Is there any way to update `PT="UNKNOWN"` unknown to any value:

```
<A N="XPgs" T="xml">&amp;lt;Pgs&amp;gt;&amp;lt;Pg PgId="00228" PSq="228" DPSq="1" PG="UNKNOWN" PT="UNKNOWN" /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/Pgs&amp;gt;</A>
```

Comment: Waht's your dbms?

Answer (score 0):

If you treat this as string, then simple replace will do:

```
UPDATE tab
SET col = REPLACE(col, 'PT="UNKNOWN"' ,'PT="NEW_VALUE"')
WHERE id = ?;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=45acd8c4e9d77ec1fbdce6e3ee29d097)**

Comment: I need to change below tag PT Vlaue from UNKNOW to new value
<A N="XPgs" T="xml">&amp;lt;Pgs&amp;gt;&amp;lt;Pg PgId="00228" PSq="228" DPSq="1" PG="UNKNOWN" PT="UNKNOWN" /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/Pgs&amp;gt;</A>

Comment: Thanks for the reply